# Problem opening multiple custom profiles with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to open several profiles

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Specify the paths to the Chrome profiles
profile1_path = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data"
profile2_path = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data"

# Set up the options and desired capabilities for each profile
options1 = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options1.add_argument("--user-data-dir=" + profile1_path)
options1.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 41')

options2 = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options2.add_argument("--user-data-dir=" + profile2_path)
options2.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 42')


# Start the first browser instance with the first profile
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(options=options1)
driver1.get("https://www.google.com")

# Start the second browser instance with the second profile
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome(options=options2)
driver2.get("https://www.google.com")
```

But the problem is that the first profile works fine, and the second opens, but does not go to the Google link.

`Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally. (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)`

Run several profiles in order to do a task

Answer (score 0):

Add profile names at the end to the below 2 lines and try:

```
profile1_path = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 41"
profile2_path = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 42"
```